# How to test if a facet of a periodic c3t3 is on the boundary

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to extract the boundary facets of a periodic c3t3, i.e. all boundary facets including those at the periodic boundaries. My current approach is to try to iterate trough all the tetrahedra and test one by one its facets with "is_infinite" (see the code snipped bellow), but  "is_infinite" is always returning false.

```
for(Cell_iterator cit = c3t3P.cells_begin(); cit !=c3t3P.cells_end(); ++cit) {
    for(int l=0; l<4; ++l) {
        const int id = V[cit->vertex(l)];
        CGAL_assertion(1 <= id && id <= medit_number_of_vertices);

        t[l] = id - 1;
        if( tr.is_infinite(cit, l) )
            std::cout << "is true!" << std::endl ;//Facet_boundary.push_back(points[t[l]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no boundary in periodic triangulations since they extend infinitely by definition. As such, there are no infinite simplices in the triangulation data structure of a periodic triangulation, and the neighbor of a cell is always another finite cell.

Of course, internally, there is only a canonical subset of these cells being represented (see this figure in 2D: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/index.html#fig__P2Triangulation2figcovering; 3D is the same). However, the boundary of this subset is completely arbitrary and does not have any geometric meaning.

Comment: You can distinguish if you are at the boundary of this (once again arbitrary) subset by checking if the neighboring finite cell has an offset, using the function `neighbor_offset()`.

However, maybe you could explain what are you trying to do at a higher level, and what did you mean by "boundary"?

Comment: @Mael: I would like to get the intersection of some arbitrary 3D shape with a 3D periodic mesh. The number of repetitions is determined by how many are needed to fill the shape. For this, I was thinking of using corefine_and_compute_intersection meaning I need both polygon meshes to bound a volume. Since the border_facets of the periodic mesh do not form a bounded volume, I am trying to manually extract the boundary facets for my arbitrary number of repetitions with the end caps, so to say. That way I can get a polygon mesh bounding a volume and can then take the intersection.

Comment: Apologies, it is still not clear to me what you are trying to do: what do you mean by "the intersection of a 3D shape with a 3D periodic mesh"? Since a periodic triangulation is infinite and covers all space, the intersection is simply your 3D shape. Do you mean that you want to refine the surface bounding your 3D shape with the periodic triangulation? Or are you trying to compute how many duplicates of a single arbitrary instance (i.e. a set of unique tetrahedra in the periodic triangulation) of the periodic triangulation are required to cover your shape?

Comment: @Mael not sure what you mean by "refine the surface bounding the 3D shape with the periodic triangulation" so don't know if this is what I mean or not. Anyway, even though it is infinite, the intersection with the shape would result in the shape minus the void space of the periodic mesh, right?. I guess you could also see it as cutting the periodic mesh with the 3D object in order to limit its domain.

Comment: So, what you are trying to obtain is the set of tetrahedra that are contained within the chosen (closed) 3D shape + the set of truncated tetrahedra resulting from the intersection with the boundary of the shape ? Is this correct?

Comment: @Mael Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you could go at your problem given the clarification in the comments above:

- Start from a point on your surface
- Use the [`locate()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_3_triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Periodic__3__triangulation__3.html#a684dbacff36aa8952313c691ced5bf2e) function of the periodic triangulation . This gives you a cell and an offset such that the point is in the tetrahedron of this cell translated by the `offset` parameter.
- You can qualify whether a vertex of the periodic triangulation is contained in the interior, on the boundary, or in the exterior of the 3D closed shape using the class [`Side_of_triangle_mesh`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classCGAL_1_1Side__of__triangle__mesh.html).
- Walk from cell to cell (using `cell->neighbor(0...3)`). Note that as you walk, you will eventually reach the border of the internal representation and will need to shift offset when going to its neighboring cell: that's the purpose of the `neighbor_offset()` function that I mentioned in the comments.
- For a given visited cell, qualify the position of its vertices as `in` (`Side_of_triangle_mesh` returns `on boundary` or `on bounded side`) or `out` (`Side_of_triangle_mesh` returns `on unbounded side`) of the shape. The position canonical position is given by `Periodic_triangulation::point(Cell_handle, index)` and you can shift it using `Periodic_triangulation::construct_point(Point, Offset)`.
- Do not explore the neighbors of a cell whose vertices are all `out`.
- Cells whose vertices are all `in` are directly in your output.
- For cells that have some vertices `in` and some vertices `out`, you could create a surface mesh from the tetrahedron (for example with [`make_tetrahedron`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#gad2e132763721d8e4fd22020c1665c15f)) and compute the intersection with the shape using the [`corefine_and_compute_intersection`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga3ff96d36cad8f37efcdada916c46fbbe).